# will the website not work if we renew SSL certificate and take time to deploy to the server

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

Due to a vulnerability in a WAF system we are required to rotate our SSL certificate on our website. we have to update the SSL certificate in several places.

My question, if I renew the SSL certificate from the CA and take time to deploy it on various servers. will this issue cause any outage on the site.

some of the places where I need to deploy:

- WAF
- Cloudfront
- Nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the old certificate is still valid (i.e. not expired and not revoked) it will continue to work so you can take some time to roll out the new certificate you've got. You can also run a mixed setup where some installations have the new certificate while others still have the old one.

While your specific use case is unknown it might be that due to the vulnerability the private key of the previous certificate was compromised which should (hopefully) lead to a quick revocation by the certificate. In this case you have to roll out the new certificates as fast as possible since due to the revocation clients might not accept the old certificate any longer.